# Prove that if $A\ge0$ then $JA$ has imaginary eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

> Let $A$ a symmetric positive definite real matrix of dimension $2n\times 2n$ and $J$ the standard symplectic matrix, with block representation
>   \begin{gather}
> J=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & -I \\ I & 0
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{gather}
>   with $I$ diagonal matrix of order $n \times n$. Consider the product $U=JA$, then there exists a basis that diagonalizes $U$ and have only imaginary eigenvalues.

How can I prove that?

Comment: Why the `algebra-precalculus` tag?

Answer (score 3):

It's simply because $JA$ is similar to $A^{1/2}JA^{1/2}$, which is skew-Hermitian.

Comment: how can you prove the similarity?